# Recover data from Samsung Galaxy A40 after factory reset

Tags: samsung, factory-reset, restore

I’m trying to recover data (especially the contacts and photos) from a Samsung Galaxy A40 that was recently factory reset. Syncing data to the Google account was disabled, so that route wasn’t successful.

I tried to get an image of the internal flash. However, with `adb shell`, I can’t access `/dev/block/mmcblk0` because of missing permissions.

I didn’t find anything particular helpful in the stock recovery. Running a custom recovery seems to require unlocking the bootloader. However that potentially opens security holes. Will that further wipe the data?

Do you have any other ideas how to recover the contacts and photos from the device?

Comment: Are you aware that recent Android devices are by default encrypted and a factory rest usually erases the used key? Thus even if you would manage to read the flash block device you will find just undecryptable garbage.

Comment: after factory reset there is nothing to recover anymore, you can therefore safely unlock bootloader now (if you still want)